# Add and print two numbers in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, io, arm

I am trying to prompt the user for two integers, and then print the sum of those two integers. I have figured out how to print a single integer, n, but I cannot print the second integer, m.

When I run this code, it works as expected, except that it prints only the value of n.

Here are the steps and my code:

```
/* 1. Prompt the user to enter an integer
* 2. Read an integer from the keyboard into memory
* 3. Prompt the user to enter another integer
* 4. Read an integer from the keyboard into memory
* 5. Load the two integers into CPU registers
* 6. Add them together
* 7. Print the result
*/

            .data
    prompt: .asciz  "Enter a number: "  @ user prompt
            .align  2
    sformat:.asciz  "%d"                @ Format string for reading an int with scanf
            .align  2
    pformat:.asciz  "The sum is: %d\n"  @ Format string for printf
            .align  2
    n:      .word   0                   @ int n = 0
    m:      .word   0                   @ int m = 0

            .text
            .global main
    main:   stmfd   sp!, {lr}       @ push lr onto stack

            @ printf("Enter a number: ")
            ldr     r0, =prompt
            bl      printf

            @ scanf("%d\0", &n)
            ldr     r0, =sformat    @ load address of format string
            ldr     r1, =n          @ load address of int n variable
            bl      scanf           @ call scanf("%d", &n)

            @ printf("Enter a number: ")
            ldr     r0, =prompt
            bl      printf

            @ scanf("%d\0" &m)
            ldr     r0, =sformat    @ load address of format string
            ldr     r2, =m          @ load address of int m variable
            bl      scanf           @ call scanf("%d", &m)

            @ printf("You entered %d\n", n)
            ldr     r0, =pformat    @ load address of format string
            ldr     r2, =m
            ldr     r2, [r2]
            ldr     r1, =n          @ load address of int variable
            ldr     r1, [r1]        @ load int variable
            add     r1, r2, r1
            bl      printf          @ call printf("You entered %d\n", n)

            ldmfd   sp!, {lr}       @ pop lr from stack
            mov     r0, #0          @ load return value
            mov     pc, lr          @ return from main
            .end
```

EDIT: I changed this bit of code to use r1 instead of r2:

```
@ scanf("%d\0" &m)
ldr     r0, =sformat    @ load address of format string
ldr     r2, =m          @ load address of int m variable
bl      scanf           @ call scanf("%d", &m)
```

This works, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Before you call `scanf()` the first time, you do `ldr     r1, =n`. Before you call it the second time, you do `ldr     r2, =m`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: I think so. I'm trying to load the address of m into r2 so I can add r1 and r2.


EDIT: I changed it to r1, and now it works, but I do not understand why.

Comment: That is irrelevant. The only relevant part is where `scanf()` is expecting the pointer corresponding to `"%d"` to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fix works because all architectures follow a certain *calling convention*, where registers are mapped to function parameters and return value. In this case, `scanf` takes two parameters so according to the [ARM EABI calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_.28A32.29)  the first parameter would be in r0 and the second in r1.